# TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I am pretty new to angularJS. I want to use a typeahead for one of my textboxes but when i use it it does that error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
>       at Scope. (http://XX.YY.ca/js/lib/ui-bootstrap.js:3426:32)
>       at fnInvoke (http://XX.YY.ca/js/lib/angular.js:10017:21)
>       at OPERATORS.| (http://XX.YY.ca/js/lib/angular.js:9532:59)
>       at Object.extend.constant [as get] (http://XX.YY.ca/js/lib/angular.js:9962:14)
>       at Scope.$digest (http://XX.YY.ca/js/lib/angular.js:11800:40)
>       at Scope.$apply (http://XX.YY.ca/js/lib/angular.js:12061:24)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (http://XX.YY.ca/js/lib/angular.js:17839:21)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.n.event.dispatch (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3:8066)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3:4767)

My code is basically the same as the one on the angular-ui website. Here it is:

Markup:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="customer" autocomplete="off"
               ng-model="nom" tabindex="0"
               typeahead="customer.customerFirstName for customer in getCustomers($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue"
               typeahead-wait-ms="300" typeahead-on-select="setId($item)"
               typeahead-editable="false" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Customer" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
    [...]
    $scope.getCustomers = function (val) {
        return $http.get('/index.php/customers/get_customers_ajax', {
            params: {val: val}
        }).then(function (res) {
            var customers = [];
            angular.forEach(res.data, function (item) {
                customers.push({
                    'customerID': item.customerID,
                    'customerFirstName': item.customerFirstName,
                    'customerLastName': item.customerLastName
                })
            })
            console.log(customers);
            return customers;
        });
    }
    $scope.setID = function ($item) {
        $scope.newOrder.customerID = $item.customerID;
        Console.log($scope.newOrder.customerID);
    }
});
```

Backend response:

```
[
    {"CustomerID":"1","CustomerLastName":"Pan","CustomerFirstName":"Petter"}, 
    {...}
]
```

I don't know what additionnal information i can provide, but if any, ask and i will post !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change this line:

```
typeahead="customer.customerFirstName for customer in getCustomers($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue"
```

It seems that the syntax should be:

```
typeahead="<name> for <name> in getCustomers($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue"
```

if `<name>` in the first position is not equal to `<name>` in second position it returns an error.

Try to change your code to:

```
typeahead="customer for customer in getCustomers($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue"
```

And in your javascript put `customerFirstName` direcly in returned array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are setting ng-model="nom", but you don't have a $scope.nom variable defined in your controller.  Angular is trying to bind the customer selected from the typeahead to a nom variable in your controller.

Comment: I have tried it, and it still doesn't work. Same error as shown up

Comment: Where are you getting $item from?  I don't see that mentioned in the Angular documentation as a provided variable.  Instead you could change your setID method so that it has a customer parameter and you call it from the HTML like: setID(customer)?  Try that and let me know if it works.  One other thing I'm curious about that you could try is the ng-model should be binding the selected value to the nom variable in your controller.  What I'm not sure about is whether it would binds just the last name or the full customer object.  If it's the customer you could get the ID from that instead.